# Imageresizer doe not crop the width but only crops the height

Tags: imageresizer

Having an issue with my images not being cropped using imageresizer. It crops fine on the height but does not crop the width.

here is an example: https://media.hillarys.co.uk/asset//media/10222/zen-collection-mishima-dawn-curtains.jpg?width=850&height=450&mode=Crop&quality=70

If I set the height to 400 it crops fine. However if I set the width to 300. It will resize the image.

This is really starting to get frustrating now. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see an image that is 850x450 pixels.

`mode=crop` (compared to mode=max or mode=pad) **minimally** crops to achieve the required aspect ratio, then scales the image down the the precise dimensions you requested.

If you don't want a *minimal* crop, then you should use `crop=x1,y1,x2,y2`. These can be expressed as percentages instead of coordinates with `cropxunits=100&cropyunits=100`.